# Web Crawling using import.io

Tags: xpath, import.io

I am trying to crawl the following website https://goo.gl/THqDhD using import.io tool. I used the connector tool to parse the whole search result for specific query (and include the pagination), and successfully chosen all the rows in the search result, but was unable to select the items'image box (as column)

import.io contain manually xpath overriding for the selected, so I tried to select images in the search results using the following xpath:

```
.//*[@id='container-inner']/div[3]/div[4]/div[*]/div[1]/div/a/
```

which should represent the columns of the table, but I got the following problem

```
What you have selected is not within a result
```

The result here is the previous selected rows, but I inspected the item box and made sure that the selection is inside. Any help please?